# How to stub target platform in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-test

Suppose I have a widget that behaves differently according to the platform:

- If the platform is Android, it shows a `RaisedButton`.
- If the platform is iOS, it shows a `CupertinoButton`.

Example:

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  if (Platform.isAndroid) 
    return buildRaisedButton();
  else if (Platform.isIOS)
    return buildCupertinoButton();
  else 
    throw UnsupportedError('Only Android and iOS are supported.');
}
```

In my [widget tests](https://flutter.dev/docs/testing#widget-tests), I want to be able to test both situations, but since `Platform`'s getters are static, I cannot stub them.

Any ideas on how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

### tl;dr

Acknowledge target platform with `Theme`:

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  final platform = Theme.of(context).platform;

  if (platform == TargetPlatform.iOS) 
    return buildCupertinoButton();
  else 
    ...
}
```

Stub target platform by setting `debugDefaultTargetPlatformOverride`:

```dart
testWidgets('`CupertinoButton` is shown in iOS.', (tester) async {
  debugDefaultTargetPlatformOverride = TargetPlatform.iOS;
  
  // run your tests

  debugDefaultTargetPlatformOverride = null;
});
```

### Acknowledging target platform

In order to make your code easier to test, the target platform should be acknowledged from the `Theme`, not from `Platform`:

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  final platform = Theme.of(context).platform;

  if (platform == TargetPlatform.android) 
    return buildRaisedButton();
  else if (platform == TargetPlatform.iOS)
    return buildCupertinoButton();
  else 
    throw UnsupportedError('Only Android and iOS are supported.');
}
```

The getter `defaultTargetPlatform` should be able to cover the cases in which you don't have access to the `BuildContext`.

### Stubbing target platform

To stub the target platform, you must set `debugDefaultTargetPlatformOverride`. By default, Android is the target platform for widget tests.

Example:

```dart
testWidgets('`CupertinoButton` is shown in iOS.', (tester) async {
  debugDefaultTargetPlatformOverride = TargetPlatform.iOS;

  await tester.pumpWidget(MyWidget());

  expect(find.byType(RaisedButton), findsNothing);
  expect(find.byType(CupertinoButton), findsOneWidget);
  
  debugDefaultTargetPlatformOverride = null;
});
```

Notice the last line: `debugDefaultTargetPlatformOverride = null`.

This is necessary because, in the binding process that happens inside the function `testWidgets()`, the method `BindingBase.initServiceExtensions()` determines — based on the OS — the value of `debugDefaultTargetPlatformOverride`. If the operating system is not mobile (Android, iOS or Fuchsia), `null` gets attributed.

At the end of the test, `testWidgets()` calls the function `debugAssertAllFoundationVarsUnset()` that checks whether `debugDefaultTargetPlatformOverride` is `null` to make sure you didn't forget to reset it to the default value. This must be done because `debugDefaultTargetPlatformOverride` is a top-level variable that persists across tests.

**Important:** You might be tempted to move `debugDefaultTargetPlatformOverride = null` to `tearDown()`, but it won't work since `debugAssertAllFoundationVarsUnset()` is called before `tearDown()`.

Answer (score 0):

In 2022 it is not recommended to use `dart:io` and `Platform` class to determine the runtime platform. The better alternative is to use `defaultTargetPlatform` available through 'package:flutter/foundation.dart'. I.e.:

```
if (defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.android ||
            defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.iOS) {}
```

Should you have that approach for determining platform in your code overiding platform in tests is as easy as setting `debugDefaultTargetPlatformOverride` in your test body.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/debugDefaultTargetPlatformOverride.html

E.g.:

```
  testWidgets('DataTable2 renders with DataRow.index()',
      (WidgetTester tester) async {
    debugDefaultTargetPlatformOverride = TargetPlatform.android;
 ...
    debugDefaultTargetPlatformOverride = null;
  });
```

Comment: > In 2022 it is not recommended to use dart:io and Platform class to determine the runtime platform

why? any source?